# Why does my Code using Selenium has such a long iteration time in a for-loop in Python? (Chromedriver)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, extract

I'm a beginner in Python, so please be patient with me.

I want to extract some simple data from an array of URLs.
All the URLs HTML-Contents have the same structur, so extracting the data by using a for-loop works out fine.

I use Selenium, because I found out, that the Websites JavaScript changes the initial HTML-Code and I want the final HTML-Code to work on.

For every iteration it takes around 4 seconds, which is accummulated a lot of time.
I already found out, that wait.until(page_has_loaded) alone takes half of the time of the code.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import requests
import openpyxl
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
driver_path = 'C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe'

dir = "C:\\Users\\Me\\OneDrive\\Dokumente_\\Notizen\\CSGOItems\\CSGOItems.xlsx"
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(dir)
sheet1 = workbook["Tabelle1"]
sheet2 = workbook["AllPrices"]

URLSkinBit = [
    'https://skinbid.com/auctions?mh=Gamma%20Case&sellType=fixed_price&skip=0&take=30&sort=price%23asc&ref=csgoskins',
    'https://skinbid.com/listings?popular=false&goodDeals=false&sort=price%23asc&take=10&skip=0&search=gamma&sellType=all',
    'https://skinbid.com/auctions?mh=Danger%20Zone%20Case&sellType=fixed_price&skip=0&take=30&sort=price%23asc&ref=csgoskins',
    'https://skinbid.com/auctions?mh=Dreams%20%26%20Nightmares%20Case&sellType=fixed_price&skip=0&take=30&sort=price%23asc&ref=csgoskins',
    'https://skinbid.com/listings?popular=false&goodDeals=false&sort=price%23asc&take=10&skip=0&search=vanguard&sellType=all',
    'https://skinbid.com/listings?popular=false&goodDeals=false&sort=price%23asc&take=10&skip=0&search=chroma%203&sellType=all',
    'https://skinbid.com/listings?popular=false&goodDeals=false&sort=price%23asc&take=10&skip=0&search=spectrum%202&sellType=all',
    'https://skinbid.com/listings?popular=false&goodDeals=false&sort=price%23asc&take=10&skip=0&search=clutch&sellType=all',
    'https://skinbid.com/listings?popular=false&goodDeals=false&sort=price%23asc&take=10&skip=0&search=snakebite&sellType=all',
    'https://skinbid.com/listings?popular=false&goodDeals=false&sort=price%23asc&take=10&skip=0&search=falchion&sellType=all',
    'https://skinbid.com/listings?popular=false&goodDeals=false&sort=price%23asc&take=10&skip=0&search=fracture&sellType=all',
    'https://skinbid.com/listings?popular=false&goodDeals=false&sort=price%23asc&take=10&skip=0&search=prisma%202&sellType=all',
]

def page_has_loaded(driver):
    return driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete"


def SkinBitPrices():
    global count3
    count3 = 0

    with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path) as driver:
        for url in URLSkinBit:

            driver.get(url)

            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            wait.until(page_has_loaded)

            html = driver.page_source

            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            container = soup.find('div', {'class': 'price'}).text

            price = float(container.replace(' € ', ''))
            print("%.2f" % price)

            #Edit Excel-File
            cell = str(3 + count3)
            sheet2['B' + cell] = price

            count3 += 1

    driver.quit()
    workbook.save(dir)
    workbook.close()
    return

SkinBitPrices()
```

Do you see possibilities to improve the performance here?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Opening and closing the driver is unnecessary. You could initialize the driver only once and use driver.get($single_url_from_the_list) to go to correct page before crawling it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response!I already tried that...
Unfortuanetly than just the first URL has correct HTML-Code.
The second will return an error, because it cant find the needed data there anymore.
So it has to do something with the drivers cache maybe? I could not find an answer to that yet.

Comment: driver itself does not cache anything.  However, you are initializing driver already at least twice .. first with context manager (the `with` line) and then second time inside the loop .. Fix your code first ?

Comment: Good point. I did that. But now when I run that, I get the expected error.
You maybe know what to do now? First Iteration already just at 2 seconds now.. That would be great if it works for all...

Comment: without seeing your full code and the urls, no i dont know  ..

Comment: Ok, I updated the Code above.

Comment: It still initializes the driver *twice*, once with the contextmanager's `with` and not passing the options into it and second time with passing the options . nor did you get rid of the driver.close() in the loop.  Each iteration still will generate webdriver instance, which opens a browser which gets closed at end of every loop .. This is where your slowness comes from, not because of selenium but because of your own code.

Comment: also replace beautiful soup with `driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("div.price")?.innerText')`

Comment: Ah, when I updated the Code above, I just added the other code around, but didnt touch the Function itself, should have done that...
I did actually delete the new Instance per Iteration line, aswell as driver.close()

Comment: Guys, that looks already really promissing, thank you for so far! Now I recognized, that driver.quit() takes 20 seconds. 
Is there something that can be done?

Comment: Ok, I came up with a solution. I let that programm run until I want to stop it, only than the driver.quit() gets called.
You really helped me. Thank you